# Embed one page in another page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I have created two separate pages `testOne` and `testTwo` which are containing some UI designs. One more page is there as `pageThree` where I need to integrate that both pages.

I'm new to WordPress and tried to implement shortCode for both pages (`testOne` and `testTwo`) but not achieved the result.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your theme's page code it might be as simple as just hooking into some action before the end of the page content (or just put the code directly into the page's code with some [conditional tags][1].

The easiest way i can think of would be doing something like this:

```
get_header(); ?>

<section id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
    <div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        
        
        if (is_page($pageThreePostId)){
            // Get the other pages
            $testOne = get_post($testOnePagePostId);
            if (!empty($testOne) && is_a($testOne,WP_Post::class)){
                echo apply_filters('the_content',$testOne->post_content);
            }

            $testTwo = get_post($testTwoPagePostId);
            if (!empty($testTwo) && is_a($testTwo,WP_Post::class)){
                echo apply_filters('the_content',$testTwo->post_content);
            }   
        }
        
        
        ?>

    </div><!-- #main -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```